# How convert strings in a File object

Tags: java

I have filepath and title of the file.
Is there a way to create a File object with these informations ?

Something like this:

```
String a = new String("/directory/name.txt");
String b = new String("This is the title");

File f = new File(a,b);
```

Comment: You can't single quote strings in Java. Try `String a = "/directory/name.txt"` and `String b = "This is the title"`

Comment: @EliSadoff sorry, it was an error of distraction

Comment: There's also no reason to use the `new String` construct as it's no faster.

Comment: Files don't have a title. What do you mean by "title". What would be, for example, the title of your Java file containing that source code?

Comment: Also, `File f = new File(a,b)` will create a file `/directory/name.txt/"This is the title"`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your title shows "convert strings in a File object"! Convert to what?

Comment: Did you even bother to *look* at the javadoc of the `File` constructor you are calling? [`File(String parent, String child)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) What do you believe `parent` and `child` means? I mean, you could *read* the javadoc, which does explain it, but just look at the names. Do either of those imply "title" to you?

Answer (score 1):

`File` has a constructor which receives a string of the location of that file on the computer.

```
File f = new File("path\\to\\your\\file");
```

Assuming that `title of the file` means its name, you can use

```
f.renameTo("newName");
```

to rename your file.

Unrelated to files: You don't need to initialize a `String`.
just write:

```
String a = "/directory/name.txt";
```

to create a string.

Comment: @cricket_007 I felt it relevant here as I am adding to the answer, so it would fit to the question better. questions are not exactly the same, so there is room for adding

Comment: @cricket_007 I think that the answer is good, as it covers more of the question.